# docker-compose COPY before running endrypoint

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

Using docker desktop with WSL2, the ultimate aim is to run a shell command to generate local SSL certs before starting an nginx service.

to `docker up` we have

```
version: '3.6'

services:
    # Frontend
    rp:
      environment:
        - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
      container_name: revproxy
      image: nginx:latest
      user: root
      restart: always
      ports: 
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
      volumes:
        - .\conf:/home/conf
        - .\scripts:/home/scripts
```

so far so good, now we would like to add a pre startup script to create the ssl certs before launching the nginx server `/home/scripts/certs.sh`

```
mkdir -p /home/ssl/certs
mkdir -p /home/ssl/private

openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -subj "/C=CA/ST=QC/O=Company, Inc./CN=zero.url" -addext "subjectAltName=DNS:mydomain.com" -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /home/ssl/private/nginx-zero.key -out /home/ssl/certs/nginx-zero.crt;
```

Now adding the following to `docker-compose.yml` causes the container to bounce between running to rebooting and keeps recreating the certs via the script the exits the container. no general error message. I assume the exit code means the container is exiting correctly, that then triggers the restart.

```
command: /bin/sh -c "/home/scripts/certs.sh"
```

following other answers, adding `exec "$@"` makes no difference.

as an alternative I tried to copy the script into the pre `nginx` launch folder `docker-entrypoint.d`. this creates an error on `docker up`

```
version: '3.6'

services:
    # Frontend
    rp:
      environment:
      - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
      container_name: revproxy
      image: nginx:latest
      user: root
      restart: always
      ports: 
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
      volumes:
        - .\conf:/home/conf
        - .\scripts:/home/scripts
      COPY /home/scripts/certs.sh /docker-entrypoint.d/certs.sh
```

this generates an error

```
ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a simple key
  in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 18, column 7
could not find expected ':'
  in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 18, column 64
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command docker-compose -f "docker-compose.yml" up -d --build" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

So what are the options for running a script before starting the primary `docker-entrypoint.sh` script

**UPDATE:**
as per suggestion in comment, changing the format of the flag did not help,

```
version: '3.6'

services:
    # Frontend
    rp:
      environment:
        - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS: 1
      container_name: revproxy
      image: nginx:latest
      user: root
      restart: always
      ports: 
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
      volumes:
        - .\conf:/home/conf
        - .\dc_scripts:/home/scripts
      COPY /home/scripts/certs.sh /docker-entrypoint.d/certs.sh

ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a simple key
  in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 17, column 7
could not find expected ':'
  in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 18, column 7
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command docker-compose -f "docker-compose.yml" up -d --build" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

Comment: the error is from `- COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1` it should be `- COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS: 1` also indented properly

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @LawrenceCherone but changing to `environment:
        - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS: 1` (indent corrected) still generates an error

Answer (score 1):

Dockerfiles are used to buid images, and contains a list of commands like RUN, EXEC and COPY. They have a very shell script like syntax with one command per line (for the most part).

A docker compose file on the other hand is a yaml formatted file that is used to deploy built images to docker as running services. You cannot put commands like `COPY` in this file.

You can, for local deployments, on non windows systems, map individual files in in the volumes section:

```yaml
      volumes:
        - .\conf:/home/conf
        - .\scripts:/home/scripts
        - ./scripts/certs.sh:/usr/local/bin/certs.sh
```

But this syntax only works on linux and MacOS hosts - I believe.

An alternative is to restructure your project with a Dockerfile and a docker-compose.yml file.

With a `Dockerfile`

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY --chmod=0755 scripts/certs.sh /usr/local/bin
ENTRYPOINT ["certs.sh"]
```

Into the docker-compose, add a build: node with the path to the Dockerfile. "." will do. `docker-compose build` will be needed to force a rebuild if the Dockerfile changes after the first time.

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
    revproxy:
      environment:
        COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS: 1
      image: nginx:custom
      build: .
      user: root
      restart: always
      ports: 
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
      volumes:
        - .\conf:/home/conf
        - .\scripts:/home/scripts
```

Now, that youve changed the entrypoint of the nginx container to your custom script, you need to chain to the original one, and call it with the original command.

So, `certs.sh` needs to look like:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# your cert setup here

# this should remove "certs.sh" from the beginning of the current parameter list.
shift 1
# and now, transfer control to the original entrypoint, with the commandline that was passed.
exec "./docker-entrypoint.sh" "$@"
```

`docker inspect nginx:latest` was used to discover the original entrypoint.

---

Added after edit:

Also, `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS` doesn't look like an environment variable that nginx is going to care about. This variable should probably be set on your windows user environment so it is available before running `docker-compose`.

```sh
C:\> set COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
C:\> docker-compose build
...
C:\> docker-compose up
...
```

Also, [nginx](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) on docker hub indicates that `/etc/nginx` is the proper configuration folder for nginx, so I don't think that mapping things to `/home/...` is going to do anything. nginx should display a default page however.

Comment: thanks for the complete write up on this solution @Chris. However I am still stuck at the reboot loop after the `certs.sh` is run. It seems the `./docker-entrypoint.sh` is being called, but as the `certs.sh` completes it triggers the shut down. Should this be output to NULL or something similar?

Comment: I presume is it now `docker-compose up` that is terminating? But the output should indicate what is going wrong.